# Completed 401 Unauthorized Error after ruby upgrade(to 2.1.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems, ruby-2.1

GemFile has

```
gem 'dm-rails', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'devise', "2.0.4" 
gem 'dm-devise', "2.0.1"
```

Errors

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 263ms
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-03 20:59:33 +0530
Processing by ApplicationController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

This has started happening after upgrading **ruby** from **1.9.3** to **2.1.3**

**OS - Mac - 10.10.1**

I was not able to login because of the above issue. I have searched everywhere but could not get the right solution. Can someone please help me in this. Have spent a lot of time already.

Comment: Have you tried different versions of Ruby to see if it started happening at some particular point? Usually an upgrade would produce errors, not new behaviour.

Comment: Nope. But in my case I need to upgrade it to ruby-2.1.3. So I need a solution for this ruby version only. It would be good to help me in finding what exactly is going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Running a wildly out of date version of Devise isn't helping here. In fact, you should **immediately** [update to at least 2.0.5](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/01/security-announcement-devise-v2-2-3-v2-1-3-v2-0-5-and-v1-5-3-released/). A service like [GemCanary](https://gemcanary.com/) can help point out problems like this.

Comment: @tadman I have tried devise-2.0.5 and devise-3.0.1, but had no luck